# Error "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview

everybody.When I use a `Button` and a `EditView` and a `ImageView` as a UI,error is happen,but app can run as I want.

Run at Debug model find: `imageView = null`, and I'm defined the id of `imageView` like `image_view` in activity_main.XML;

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button send_Button;
    private EditText editText;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        send_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        send_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String inputText = editText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, inputText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type at there."
        android:maxLines="2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Read_From_Edit"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/test_photo"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve the problem? Thx!

Comment: your layout for the activity  is `activity_main` not `activity_view` which holds the view's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**EDIT 1**

> Project --> Clean

then run again.

Comment: Oh, no. Still have the problem.But thank u very much :D

Comment: the error is:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo. at MainActivity :imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view).

Comment: Thx! I solve the problem! thank u very much, and wish have a good play! :D

Comment: OK, but I'm not sure I accept your answer or not, I can use stackoverflow relaxedly.If I'm not accept your answer, maybe you can teach me :D I'm sorry about it...